# Upgrade to 1.9 admin blank page

Tags: admin, ce-1.9.0.1

I have a magento site that I rarely check but is set to auto update on its own. Today I tried to go to /admin and I got a blank page. Has anyone had this issue after updating to version 1.9? I deleted cache and session folders and there are no applicable errors in logs on server or var folder.

Comment: take a look at your apache ( or nginx ) logs

Comment: I've checked "Error Log" in Cpanel. Where would I find these logs in cpanel? I don't have sudo user access.

Comment: i've never used cPanel but maybe this could help you [click](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/ErrorLog)

Comment: Automatic updates?  Probably not a good idea to do that with Magento :/

Comment: Lmao, I know but this magento I use mostly for development purposes. I guess I might just have to die() everywhere until I figure it out.

Comment: @CaitlinHavener Did you ever figure this out. I'm having exactly the same problem here with a dev installation of Magento. :)